# Cannot resolve android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I cannot resolve android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog. this error.its always red in my eclipse. Despite I have the android-support-v7-appcompat.jar in my libs folder, and am able use android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
and android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

Comment: Which version of the support library are you using?

Comment: It requires the appCompat v22.1+

Answer (score 2):

Do you have android-support-v4.jar in your libs?

You need to make sure that all dependencies of android-support-v7-appcompat.jar are met. That is one of the primary reasons why using gradle for build is recommended.

Answer (score 1):

In your build.gradle file, under dependencies, add

```
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
```

And do a build.